# Viewport scrolling fadeout and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm ussing plugin jquery .viewport  , when i scrolldown in element #section it's well but when i scroll to up to header it's hidden 
i'm sorry for my english it's not very good

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

**STYLE**

```
    .header{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
.tab{
  margin-top:250px;

}
.section{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post-logo').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    $('.title').addClass('animated fadeInUp');

       ;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));

$(window).scroll(function(){

$("#header").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) $(this).addClass("animated fadeOut")
    else $(this).removeClass("animated fadeOut").addClass("animated fadeIn")
});

  });

});
```